# Cloudant : query in http navigator

Tags: nosql, cloudant

I'm using cloudant, with no auth, Cors enabled.

it works very well, Limit and skip working good.

but i can't find how to search for something .

I'm trying to find a document where cp is 24000 , for example with this query :

```
https://1c54473b-be6e-42d6-b914-d0ecae937981-bluemix.cloudant.com/etablissements/_all_docs?skip=0&limit=10&include_docs=true&q=cp:24000
```

But, the query doesn't return the right document.

I've also tried

```
   https://1c54473b-be6e-42d6-b914-d0ecae937981-bluemix.cloudant.com/etablissements/_all_docs?skip=0&limit=10&include_docs=true&_search({'cp':24000})
```

with no luck.

oh, and by the way, do you know if jquery.couch.js lib has been discontinued? I cant even find it on github, nor on my hard disk while im using foxant, and it is not in the directory also..

Answer (score 0):

The `/db/_all_docs` endpoint hits the primary index of the database where all of the documents in the database can be found in `_id` order.

If you wish to query the database to get a subset of the data you have three options

- [Cloudant Query](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#query) - hit the `POST /db/_find` endpoint passing in a JavaScript object containing the `selector` which defines the query you wish to perform (like the WHERE clause of a SQL query) e.g. `{selector: {cp: 24000}}`
- [MapReduce](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/creating_views.html#views-mapreduce-) - create a Map function in a design document that filters the documents you are interested it. It creates a materialized view that can be queried and filtered later. e.g. `function(doc){ emit(doc.cp, null);}`
- [Cloudant Search](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search) - this uses the Apache Lucene library to generate an index on the fields you specify. You can then query the index: `q=cp:24000`, which looks similar to the query you are looking to perform.

Comment: Thanks very  a lot , I really appreciate it ! I'm currently making tests based on  your excellent answer

Comment: Still fail to do it, i've done another post there :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590679/couchdb-jquery-couch-cant-do-a-find-query